# Metafor package: RMA and testing for interaction in two studies (Altman & Bland 2003)

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis

I have traditionally used this simple test of interaction (http://www.bmj.com/content/326/7382/219) for comparing effect sizes between studies, and I would like to start performing it in R. Although I have scripted a custom function for it, I have also been told about the "metafor" package and decided to give it a try. However, I am not able to reproduce the results of the paper using the *rma* function, probably because I do not understand the statistical basis behind it. Using the log RRs (-0.4005 and -0.1278) and SEs (0.1929 and 0.1070) from the paper, if I try to fit a fixed-effects model, here is what I get:

```
Fixed-Effects Model (k = 2)

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
 -0.1920   0.0936  -2.0518   0.0402  -0.3754  -0.0086        *
```

I thought it could be due to the inverse-variance weighting, and when I disabled it the estimate got closer to that of the paper, but the standard error is still off by a wide margin, and so are the rest of the values.

```
Fixed-Effects Model (k = 2)

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
 -0.2642   0.1103  -2.3950   0.0166  -0.4803  -0.0480        *
```

So, I'm assuming that the z-values shown in the Altman & Bland paper and in the *rma* output are different. Does someone know what their difference is? Can the fixed-effects model included in "metafor" be used for these kind of simple interaction tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question: Yes. What you are doing is pooling the two log RRs, when in fact you want to compare them. You can do that easily by adding a dummy variable to the model and testing the corresponding coefficient. Let me reproduce the results from the paper you cited:

```
library(metafor)

yi  <- c(-0.4005, -0.1278) # the log RRs
sei <- c(0.1929, 0.1070)   # corresponding SEs
xi  <- c(1,0)              # dummy variable

res <- rma(yi, sei=sei, mods = ~ xi, method="FE")
res
```

This yields:

```
Fixed-Effects with Moderators Model (k = 2)

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 0) = 0.0000, p-val = 1.0000

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2): 
QM(df = 1) = 1.5283, p-val = 0.2164

Model Results:

                      se     zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
intrcpt  -0.1278  0.1070  -1.1944  0.2323  -0.3375  0.0819   
xi       -0.2727  0.2206  -1.2362  0.2164  -0.7050  0.1596   

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The results given under the `Model Results` for the dummy variable (`xi`) correspond to those given in the paper (the minor discrepancies are due to rounding errors).

To get the ratio of relative risks, you can use:

```
predict(res, newmods=1, intercept=FALSE, transf=exp, digits=2)
```

This yields:

```
  pred ci.lb ci.ub
1 0.76  0.49  1.17
```

Again, the same as given in the paper.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! :) I was reading about moderators and I thought the answer might lie there somewhere, but wasn't quite seeing it. Now its very clear!